Minimizing the chance of majority successes in repeated IID bernoulli trials
Let $\frac{1}{2} <p <1$ and let $X\sim\mathcal{B}(n,p)$ so that
$$\mathbb{P}(X=k) = {n \choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}.$$
Consider the probability of the event "the majority are successes"
$$m(n):= \mathbb{P}(X\geq \lceil{\frac{n}{2}}\rceil)=1-\sum_{k=0}^{\lceil \frac{n}{2}\rceil-1}{n \choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}.$$
Here is a plot for $n=2k$, $k=1,\dotsc, 500$ and $p=0.51$. We can see a local minimum early on.
Question:
What (approximate) value of $n$ gives the minimum of $m(n)$? (over just $n$ even would be nice).
The CLT does not appear to be useful here, since we are not necessarily interested in $n\to \infty$ (for $p=0.51$ the minimum appears to occur around $n\approx 50$).

Normal approximation:
If we use the normal approximation then
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(X\geq \lceil n/2 \rceil ) & = 1- \mathbb{P}(X\leq \lceil n/2\rceil-1)\\
& \approx 1- \mathbb{P}\left(Z\leq \frac{\lceil n/2\rceil-1-np}{\sqrt{npq}}\right)\\
& = 1-\Phi\left(\frac{\lceil n/2\rceil-1-np}{\sqrt{npq}}\right)
\end{align*}
We can drop the ceiling since we are interested in the even $n$ case. So we try to optimize
$$f(x) = 1-\Phi\left(\frac{x/2-1-xp}{\sqrt{xpq}}\right)$$
We see that
$$ f'(x) = -\phi\left(\frac{x/2-1-xp}{\sqrt{xpq}}\right) \cdot \frac{2+(1-2p)x}{4x \sqrt{xpq}}=0$$
if and only if
$$2 +(1-2p)x=0,$$
i.e. $x = 2/(2p-1)$. We can see empirically this is not quite good enough: for $p=0.51$, we have $x^*=100$ and this not is near the minimum graphically: 

If you assume $X \sim N(np, np(1 - p))$, is there a closed form solution?

@Kakashi When I first tried I could not find a closed form, but maybe I made a mistake. I'll try again and add an edit.

@Kakashi I added an edit showing there is a closed form solution if you use the normal approximation, however, it is not that good. Maybe a continuity correction would improve it though, which I'll look into later.

with continuity correction you get $n^{*} = \frac{1}{2p - 1}$.

@Kakashi Nice. That's it. If you want to post that as an answer, I'll gladly accept it. If not, I will write it up myself for completion.

Recall that the continuity correction for approximating Binomial RVs with Normal RVs is
$$ \mathbb{P}(X\leq x) \approx \mathbb{P}\left(Z \leq \frac{x+1/2-np}{\sqrt{npq}}\right),$$
where $X\sim\mathcal{B}(n,p)$ and $Z\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.
Thus, applying the normal approximation with the continuity correction gives
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(X\geq \lceil n/2 \rceil ) & = 1- \mathbb{P}(X\leq \lceil n/2\rceil-1)\\
& \approx 1- \mathbb{P}\left(Z\leq \frac{\lceil n/2\rceil-1/2-np}{\sqrt{npq}}\right)\\
& = 1-\Phi\left(\frac{\lceil n/2\rceil-1/2-np}{\sqrt{npq}}\right)
\end{align*}
We can drop the ceiling since we are interested in the even $n$ case. So we try to optimize
$$f(x) = 1-\Phi\left(\frac{x/2-1/2-xp}{\sqrt{xpq}}\right)$$
We see that
$$ f'(x) = -\phi\left(\frac{x/2-1/2-xp}{\sqrt{xpq}}\right) \cdot \frac{pq(1+x(1-2p))}{4(pqx)^{3/2}}=0$$
if and only if
$$1 +(1-2p)x=0,$$
i.e. $x = 1/(2p-1)$. Interested readers can verify that this gives a local minimum for $f(x)$. Therefore, the approximate optimal $n$ is
$$n^* \approx \frac{1}{2p-1}$$

